# PyTorch, Bert model: optimizer zero_grad() error

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, bert-language-model, named-entity-recognition

I am relatively new to Python, and I am following a tutorial(https://towardsdatascience.com/named-entity-recognition-with-bert-in-pytorch-a454405e0b6a) regarding bert training for a task that I need.
The tutorial is relatively new, of May 2022.
I am using python 3.10.6 and pytorch 1.13.1+cpu and tensorflow 2.11 at ubuntu 22.04.

I am receiving the following error regarding the SGD optimizer:

> builtins.AttributeError: 'SGD' object has no attribute 'zero_grad'

The problem is in the train_loop() function of the tutorial. It has a line:

> optimizer.zero_grad()

I read that the zero_grad() has been deprecated from tf and tried to modify it with some similar that were proposed as solution:

> optimizer.cleargrads()

but I receive the following error in that case:

> builtins.AttributeError: 'BertModel' object has no attribute 'cleargrads'

The code is of approx 200 lines in total. It exists in the tutorial(https://towardsdatascience.com/named-entity-recognition-with-bert-in-pytorch-a454405e0b6a)

I can post the full code in case is needed to appear in the post.

I add all the code as requested:

```
import pandas as pd
from transformers import BertTokenizerFast
import torch
from transformers import BertForTokenClassification
import numpy as np
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from keras.optimizers import SGD, Adam
from tqdm import tqdm 
df = pd.read_csv('/home/stathis/Desktop/res/ref/bert/ner.csv')
print(df.head())
labels = [i.split() for i in df['labels'].values.tolist()]
unique_labels = set()

for lb in labels:
  [unique_labels.add(i) for i in lb if i not in unique_labels]
 
print(unique_labels)
labels_to_ids = {k: v for v, k in enumerate(sorted(unique_labels))}
ids_to_labels = {v: k for v, k in enumerate(sorted(unique_labels))}
print(labels_to_ids)
# Let's take a look at how can we preprocess the text - Take first example
text = df['text'].values.tolist()
example = text[36]
print(example)
tokenizer = BertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased')
text_tokenized = tokenizer(example, 
                           padding='max_length', 
                           max_length=512, 
                           truncation=True, 
                           return_tensors="pt")

print(text_tokenized)
print(tokenizer.decode(text_tokenized.input_ids[0]))

print(tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(text_tokenized["input_ids"][0]))

word_ids = text_tokenized.word_ids()
print(tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(text_tokenized["input_ids"][0]))
print(word_ids)

def align_label_example(tokenized_input, labels):

        word_ids = tokenized_input.word_ids()

        previous_word_idx = None
        label_ids = []
   
        for word_idx in word_ids:

            if word_idx is None:
                label_ids.append(-100)
                
            elif word_idx != previous_word_idx:
                try:
                  label_ids.append(labels_to_ids[labels[word_idx]])
                except:
                  label_ids.append(-100)
        
            else:
                label_ids.append(labels_to_ids[labels[word_idx]] if label_all_tokens else -100)
            previous_word_idx = word_idx
      

        return label_ids
  
label = labels[36]
label_all_tokens = True
new_label = align_label_example(text_tokenized, label)
print(new_label)
print(tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(text_tokenized["input_ids"][0]))
label_all_tokens = False
new_label = align_label_example(text_tokenized, label)
print(new_label)
print(tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(text_tokenized["input_ids"][0]))
def align_label(texts, labels):
    tokenized_inputs = tokenizer(texts, padding='max_length', max_length=512, truncation=True)

    word_ids = tokenized_inputs.word_ids()

    previous_word_idx = None
    label_ids = []

    for word_idx in word_ids:

        if word_idx is None:
            label_ids.append(-100)

        elif word_idx != previous_word_idx:
            try:
                label_ids.append(labels_to_ids[labels[word_idx]])
            except:
                label_ids.append(-100)
        else:
            try:
                label_ids.append(labels_to_ids[labels[word_idx]] if label_all_tokens else -100)
            except:
                label_ids.append(-100)
        previous_word_idx = word_idx

    return label_ids

class DataSequence(torch.utils.data.Dataset):

    def __init__(self, df):

        lb = [i.split() for i in df['labels'].values.tolist()]
        txt = df['text'].values.tolist()
        self.texts = [tokenizer(str(i),
                               padding='max_length', max_length = 512, truncation=True, return_tensors="pt") for i in txt]
        self.labels = [align_label(i,j) for i,j in zip(txt, lb)]

    def __len__(self):

        return len(self.labels)

    def get_batch_data(self, idx):

        return self.texts[idx]

    def get_batch_labels(self, idx):

        return torch.LongTensor(self.labels[idx])

    def __getitem__(self, idx):

        batch_data = self.get_batch_data(idx)
        batch_labels = self.get_batch_labels(idx)

        return batch_data, batch_labels
      

df = df[0:1000]
df_train, df_val, df_test = np.split(df.sample(frac=1, random_state=42),
                            [int(.8 * len(df)), int(.9 * len(df))])

class BertModel(torch.nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):

        super(BertModel, self).__init__()

        self.bert = BertForTokenClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased', num_labels=len(unique_labels))

    def forward(self, input_id, mask, label):

        output = self.bert(input_ids=input_id, attention_mask=mask, labels=label, return_dict=False)

        return output
    
def train_loop(model, df_train, df_val):

    train_dataset = DataSequence(df_train)
    val_dataset = DataSequence(df_val)

    train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, num_workers=4, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True)
    val_dataloader = DataLoader(val_dataset, num_workers=4, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)

    use_cuda = torch.cuda.is_available()
    device = torch.device("cuda" if use_cuda else "cpu")

    optimizer = SGD(model.parameters(), lr=LEARNING_RATE)

    if use_cuda:
        model = model.cuda()

    best_acc = 0
    best_loss = 1000

    for epoch_num in range(EPOCHS):

        total_acc_train = 0
        total_loss_train = 0

        model.train()

        for train_data, train_label in tqdm(train_dataloader):

            train_label = train_label.to(device)
            mask = train_data['attention_mask'].squeeze(1).to(device)
            input_id = train_data['input_ids'].squeeze(1).to(device)

            optimizer.zero_grad()
            #optimizer.cleargrads()
            #model.zerograds()
            loss, logits = model(input_id, mask, train_label)

            for i in range(logits.shape[0]):

              logits_clean = logits[i][train_label[i] != -100]
              label_clean = train_label[i][train_label[i] != -100]

              predictions = logits_clean.argmax(dim=1)
              acc = (predictions == label_clean).float().mean()
              total_acc_train += acc
              total_loss_train += loss.item()

            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

        model.eval()

        total_acc_val = 0
        total_loss_val = 0

        for val_data, val_label in val_dataloader:

            val_label = val_label.to(device)
            mask = val_data['attention_mask'].squeeze(1).to(device)
            input_id = val_data['input_ids'].squeeze(1).to(device)

            loss, logits = model(input_id, mask, val_label)

            for i in range(logits.shape[0]):

              logits_clean = logits[i][val_label[i] != -100]
              label_clean = val_label[i][val_label[i] != -100]

              predictions = logits_clean.argmax(dim=1)
              acc = (predictions == label_clean).float().mean()
              total_acc_val += acc
              total_loss_val += loss.item()

        val_accuracy = total_acc_val / len(df_val)
        val_loss = total_loss_val / len(df_val)

        print(
                      'Epochs: {epoch_num + 1} | Loss: {total_loss_train / len(df_train): .3f} | Accuracy: {total_acc_train / len(df_train): .3f} | Val_Loss: {total_loss_val / len(df_val): .3f} | Accuracy: {total_acc_val / len(df_val): .3f}')

LEARNING_RATE = 5e-3
EPOCHS = 5
BATCH_SIZE = 2

model = BertModel()
train_loop(model, df_train, df_val)
```

And the full error message:

> - Avoid using `tokenizers` before the fork if possible
>
>   - Explicitly set the environment variable TOKENIZERS_PARALLELISM=(true | false)
>
>   0%|          | 0/400 [00:00<?, ?it/s]Traceback (most recent call
>   last):   File "/home/stathis/Desktop/untitled-1.py", line 234, in
>
>   train_loop(model, df_train, df_val)   File "/home/stathis/Desktop/untitled-1.py", line 182, in 
>   optimizer.zero_grad()   File "/home/stathis/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py",
>   line 984, in **getattribute**
>   raise e   File "/home/stathis/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py",
>   line 974, in **getattribute**
>   return super().**getattribute**(name) builtins.AttributeError: 'SGD' object has no attribute 'zero_grad'

Comment: Please post the relevant code and the full error message including line number and stack trace

Comment: Also try `.zerograds()`

Comment: This looks relevant https://github.com/chainer/chainer/issues/2971

Answer (score 0):

The proposed solution was to change
`optimizer.zero_grads()` to `model.cleargrads()`